Issue with getting a transaction in Quarkus with Hibernate
I'm trying to add to my topology to pull messages off a kafka topic, do some logic and then write to postgres. At the moment I'm just trying to get it wired together in the simplest possible way but I'm quite new to quarkus.
In my TopologyBuilder I have:
@Inject
EntityManager em;

...

StreamsBuilder streamsbuilder = new StreamsBuilder()

...

streamsBuilder.stream(rdbmsTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), QUINE_ALERT_SERDES)).process(() -> new AlertService(em));

and then that service looks like
@ApplicationScoped
public class AlertService implements Processor<String, QuineOutput, Object, Object> {
    EntityManager em;

    public AlertService(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Transactional
    void persistAlert(Alert alert) {
        em.persist(alert);
    }
    @Override
    public void process(Record<String, QuineOutput> record) {
        Log.warn("here for persist");
        persistAlert(record.value().getData().getAlertNode());
    }
}

But I get the error:
Caused by: jakarta.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: Cannot use the EntityManager/Session because neither a transaction nor a CDI request context is active. Consider adding @Transactional to your method to automatically activate a transaction, or @ActivateRequestContext if you have valid reasons not to use transactions.

I've tried adding the request context annotation, and I've tried shoving around some of the logic, I've ensured that I have an EntityManager available and the data getting passed to it is present and the class is annotated as an @Entity etc.
I'm expecting to be able to write to postgres in a transaction.

Interceptors doesn't work on beans instantiated via new operator; you have to @Inject AlertService in TopologyBuilder (and - of course - TopologyBuilder must be a managed bean and not one created via new).

As @Lucca Basso Ricci hinted at, by using new on a CDI bean, you're effectively bypassing CDI and all its features, including in particular injection and decorators.
You should never use new with CDI beans, except in very specific places (@Produces methods, which you don't need here).
In your case, replace this:
@Inject
EntityManager em;

...

StreamsBuilder streamsbuilder = new StreamsBuilder()

...

streamsBuilder.stream(rdbmsTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), QUINE_ALERT_SERDES))
        .process(() -> new AlertService(em));

With this:
@Inject
AlertService alertService; // CHANGE HERE!

...

StreamsBuilder streamsbuilder = new StreamsBuilder()

...
streamsBuilder.stream(rdbmsTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), QUINE_ALERT_SERDES))
        .process(() -> alertService); // CHANGE HERE!

And this:
@ApplicationScoped
public class AlertService implements Processor<String, QuineOutput, Object, Object> {
    EntityManager em;

    public AlertService(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Transactional
    void persistAlert(Alert alert) {
        em.persist(alert);
    }
    @Override
    public void process(Record<String, QuineOutput> record) {
        Log.warn("here for persist");
        persistAlert(record.value().getData().getAlertNode());
    }
}

With this:
@ApplicationScoped
public class AlertService implements Processor<String, QuineOutput, Object, Object> {
    EntityManager em;

    @Inject // CHANGE HERE!
    public AlertService(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Transactional
    void persistAlert(Alert alert) {
        em.persist(alert);
    }
    @Override
    public void process(Record<String, QuineOutput> record) {
        Log.warn("here for persist");
        persistAlert(record.value().getData().getAlertNode());
    }
}

